# What is the name of this component?

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

i'm searching for the name of the following component.

[image: example from an app]

It is a switch view, so you can switch through something like pictures(in this case it is text).

Comment: The closest to that is ViewPager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Component you are asking about is called [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) .

See the working [example](http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial) of ViewPager .

There are many libraries made for App Introduction , link of one of them is below , Please check .

https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3206